# Objective-C Reference to object that implements protocol

Tags: objective-c, reference, copy, protocols

I want to create a reference to an object that implements a protocol. This is an example code:

```
@interface TestClass ()
@property id <TestProtocol> testProperty;
@end

@implementation TestClass
+(id)init :(id <TestProtocol> test)
{
    TestClass *testClass = [[TestClass alloc] init]; 
    testClass.testProperty = test;
    return testClass;
}
@end
```

Does it then create a copy of the test object that implements the protocol or a reference? I'm wondering since there is no "*" sign. If it is a copy how do I then create a reference instead?

Comment: Questions seems a little bit unclear. Can you provide some more info on what do you want to achieve with this code? id is a **reference** to an object of any class. "*" is implicit in that case. I suggest you to use -initWithTest: naming instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `id` is a pointer type that can hold a pointer to any object.

There is no type in Objective-C that holds an "object" itself. Objects can only be used through pointers to objects.